# MySQL optimized join query with "OR" condition

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, entity-attribute-value

I have a database with 500k company profiles + locations they provide their services in.
So I have companies table + locations table.
Company can serve in the whole country or only in a city.
Locations table looks like this:

```
ID | company_id       | scope     | country_id | city_id
1  | 'companyuuid...' | 'city'    | 'UK'       | '32321'
2  | 'companyuuid...' | 'country' | 'US'       | NULL
```

When company provides services in the whole country we indicate scope "country" and we have scope "city" when company provides service only within specific city.

Unfortunately MySQL is pretty slow processing queries when they have "OR" statement and considering amount if data we need to work with, queries should be as optimized as possible.

```
select distinct companies.id from companies

inner join locations on companies.id = locations.company_id
and (locations.scope = 'city' and locations.city_id = '703448' ) 

order by companies.score desc limit 12 offset 0
```

My current problem is that when searching for companies within a city, I also need to show companies that provide services within the whole country. Obvious way would be adding OR statement like this:

```
select distinct companies.id from companies

inner join locations on companies.id = locations.company_id
and (locations.scope = 'city' and locations.city_id = '703448' ) 
or (locations.scope = 'country' and locations.country_id = 'UK' ) 
order by companies.score desc limit 12 offset 0
```

BUT the problem is that OR statement will make the query extremely slow. 
Is there any other way to use additional join maybe, so we can keep the query fast?

Comment: you might want to break up the queries and use `union` instead of `or`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists`:

```
select c.id
from companies c
where exists (select 1
              from locations l
              where l.company_id = c.id and
                    l.scope = 'city' and
                    l.city_id = 703448  -- I'm guessing city_id is a number, so no quotes
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from locations l
              where l.company_id = c.id and l.scope = 'country'
             )
order by c.score desc
limit 12 offset 0;
```

The `exists` subqueries can make use of an index on `locations(company_id, scope, city_id)`.  The query might even be able to take advantage of an index on `companies(score)`.

Comment: Thank you. I just tested it. It works well except it does not solve my problem, unfortunately. This query takes 3.8 seconds and using "join" query takes just 6ms.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze . . . The `join` with the `or` takes just 6 ms?  That's impressive.  Do you have the recommended `join`s for this query?

Comment: No, wrote about the join as I had in the first example. Without or's. Currently I have 500k companies but will be adding another 10m so if the lookup time will grow linearly 3.8 seconds will be too much. That's why I am looking for the most optimal solution. I am using hp z820 machine with 256GB of ram and all the data fits in memory but when MySQL starts to calculate something which happens after using OR's or IF's then performance really degrades.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze . . . You need to compare this to the version with `or`.  And you need to create the indexes for optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I actually have indexes everywhere (I am probably even overusing them but that should not harm performance, I think). With "OR" statement the same query is taking around 60 seconds. Your proposed solution is 20x faster than using OR. I was using mongo initially, maybe I should store data in companies table as json and add indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:  `OR` seems "wrong".  Do you want all the cities in the UK, plus all the Londons, including the one in Canada.

You probably want `AND` instead of `OR`.  And you would need a "self join" to reach into `locations` twice??  EAV schema sucks.

Problem 2:  `x AND y OR z` is `(x AND y) OR z`, not `x AND (y OR z)`.